# REST calls not working on AWS with localhost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat8

I'm running a Spring application on an AWS box. The app is being hosted with Tomcat 8 and the build is running great. However, the calls we are making to the back don't work using localhost but do work when we use the ip instead.

Shouldn't we be able to use localhost instead of the ip? Is this a configuration issue with Tomcat 8 on our box and if so, what do we need to fix?

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of local host and see if they work?

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason can be a configuration issue in Tomcat, however, i think there is a higher probability of a missing configuration on the machine itself. I guess this is a Linux box, maybe a line missing in /etc/hosts (like the one below)?

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: So this would let me use "localhost" instead of 127.0.0.1 in my calls? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, it should be.